# How to convert a sentence of morse code into English

Tags: python-3.6

I am using a reverse lookup to turn morse code into English and so far I am able to translate only letters at a time.  I am struggling to figure out how to translate a sentence of morse code.

I have tried to use methods such as join() but I am new to python and did not effectively use it.  Could this be a possible tool for this problem?

```
def english_morse(d, uncoded):
  a_list = []
  for key in d:
    if morse_code[key] == uncoded:
      a_list.append(key)
      print(a_list)
english_morse(morse_code,'.-')
```

I have a dictionary with the letters (keys) corresponding to morse code (values).  I want to be able to convert a sentence into morse code and I cannot use input()

Comment: There isn't any need for the loop, or even for the function.  Just reverse the keys and values in your "morse_code" mapping.  I.e. ``morse_code['.-']`` should have the value "A".

Comment: Are you saying ot make anouther dictionary?

Comment: Yes.  I'm saying that your entire function could be replaced by a simple dictionary.  Just define two dictionaries:  E.g. ``latin_to_mose['A']`` evaluates as ".-", and ``morse_to_latin[".-"]`` evaluates to "A".